# Using NSMutableAttributedString in my UITextView but now user cannot edit text [cut, copy, delete]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableattributedstring

Using `NSMutableAttributedString` to color my strings in `UITextField`, but then user cannot cut, copy, or delete the strings. For example, using the code below, if I type "blue red @green" then try to just delete out blue or cut out blue, when I try the cursor moves to the last letter in the `UITextfield`?

Any suggestions?

```
- (void)colorText {
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.thing.text];

NSArray *words=[self.thing.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

for (NSString *word in words) {
    if([word isEqualToString:@""]) {continue;};
    if ([word hasPrefix:@"@"]) {
        NSRange range=[self.thing.text rangeOfString:word];
        [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:range];
    } else {
        NSRange range=[self.thing.text rangeOfString:word];
        [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor darkGrayColor] range:range];
    }
}
[self.thing setAttributedText:string];
}
```

Comment: When are you calling this method?

Comment: In shouldChangeCharactersInRange:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the text of the string each time, which wipes the current string and puts in a new one, which moves your cursor to the end and overrides any edits you were going to make to the original string. You could make the edits yourself, call `colorText` and then return `NO`, which will make your edits but you'll still have the cursor problem.

The solution is to get the range of the cursor, make the edits manually, call `colorText`, put the cursor back to where it should be, and then return `NO`. I know it sounds convoluted, but the code isn't too bad.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    UITextPosition *beginning = textField.beginningOfDocument;
    UITextPosition *cursorLocation = [textField positionFromPosition:beginning offset:(range.location + string.length)];

    textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    [textField colorText]; // or however you call this on your field

    // cursorLocation will be (null) if you're inputting text at the end of the string
    // if already at the end, no need to change location as it will default to end anyway
    if(cursorLocation)
    {
        // set start/end location to same spot so that nothing is highlighted
        [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:cursorLocation toPosition:cursorLocation];
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to get stringByReplacingCharactersInRange to work but couldn't figure out when to use it.